# Rear Derailleur Noises

Tags: derailleur, noise

When I pedal on my bike there is a loud noise that increases as I go into easier gears on the cassette and in the easiest gear I can see the chain catching on the derailleur jockey wheels, why is this?  The chain is 1 month old?

Any help is great and feel free to ask questions about the problem.

---

Thanks everyone, the noise is coming from where the chain comes off the jockey wheels and is catching on that, I can see it, do I need new jockey wheels as the chain is already new, I have threaded the chin correctly.

Comment: Worn jockey wheels, twisted derailleur hanger, worn derailleur pivots, damaged derailleur cage. Any of those look likely?

Comment: It's the chain threaded correctly between the jockey wheels?  There's usually a lug on the cage and it's easy to thread the chain on the wrong side of it.

Comment: Incorrect indexing of the RD or incorrect trimming of the FD.

Comment: Good photos of the rear derailleur/cassette area and how the chain is routed would help us provide better suggestions.  Also, where exactly is the noise coming from? If you flip the bike upside down and turn the pedal with your hand, you'll be able to observe the whole chainline.

Comment: On one occasion, I had a chain that was a little out of spec that would catch on the upper pulley instead of cleanly releasing and engaging the cassette cog on it’s circuitous path through the drivetrain. It was noisy too. The chain turned out to be a little narrower between the inner plates than normal. That combined with an Ultegra 8000 rear derailleur’s upper pulley having long gear teeth created an interference fit between the chain and pulley. I moved the (new) chain to a 6800 RD with a forgiving pulley and no problem. I haven’t had another narrower chain like that since.